# Define extra properties for an existing class in RDFS?

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, schema.org, rdfs

I want to create a RDFS schema about venue info which contains for example:

address info and `xxx` info.

I find another schema about it:https://schema.org/Place. It contains more properties about address info but no info about `xxx`.

So

**Should I make my schema venue as a subclass of https://schema.org/Place
and add new properties?**

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:place="https://schema.org/Place#"
    xml:base="http://localhost:3000/VenueSchema#">
    <rdfs:Class rdf:ID="Venue">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://schema.org/Place"/>
    </rdfs:Class>
    <rdf:Property rdf:ID="xxx">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource= "#Venue">
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal"/>
    </rdf:Property>

    </rdf:RDF>
```

**If I use subclass, does the venue automatically have properties from the https://schema.org/Place?**

**Or instead of subclassing, I should just reuse https://schema.org/Place but declare extra properties for https://schema.org/Place?** Something like the following code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xmlns:place="https://schema.org/Place#"
xml:base="http://localhost:3000/VenueSchema#">

<rdf:Property rdf:ID="xxx">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource= "https://schema.org/Place">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal"/>
</rdf:Property>

</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: May I ask, out of interest, why you are using RDF/XML instead of a more "human friendly" RDF serialization (like Turtle)?

Comment: @unor Perhaps because everyone else does?  Google "rdfs example" and see what (non)variety of syntaxes you come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Should I make my schema venue as a subclass of https://schema.org/Place and add new properties?*

If you're declaring a describing a class **Venue**, it makes sense to make it a subclass of some other **Place** class that someone else has declared, if you want to achieve some measure of interoperability with that vocabulary.  That just means you'd do **Venue rdfs:subClassOf Place**.

> *If I use subclass, does the venue automatically have properties from the https://schema.org/Place?*

RDFS (and OWL) classes aren't quite the same thing as classes in an object oriented programming language.  Properties don't "belong" to classes, and classes don't "inherit" properties from their superclasses.

When you say that the domain of a property P is a class D, it means that that when you have a triple **x P y**, you can *infer* that **x rdf:type D**.

So, you can use any of the properties that have the domain **Place** with your instances of **Venue**, and you won't be inferring any additional information about them (except for the property assertion).
That is, if you already know that **v** is a **Venue**, and use a property **p** whose domain is **Place** with it, you can infer that **v** is a **Place**, but you could already do that because you asserted that **Venue** is a subclass of **Place**.

> *Or instead of subclassing, I should just reuse https://schema.org/Place but declare extra properties for https://schema.org/Place? Something like the following code:*

You can declare new properties that have **Place** as a domain as well.  All that the domain axioms mean is that if the property is used with some individual, then you can infer that the individual is a **Place**.